# Windows 7 don't use VPN connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn, pptp

I have a Windows 7 computer connected to a VPN (PPTP). This VPN is only being used to access a remote server, and is quite slow. So, I'd like to browse the internet directly, not over the VPN. On OS X, this is accomplished by unchecking the "Send all traffic over VPN" box, but I can't find a similar option in Windows. Long story short, how do I make it so only traffic bound for the VPNs address block is routed through the VPN?

Comment: It should do this already...? Just as OSX does. The tick box on OSX is unchecked by default so it, too, determines if traffic is bound for the VPN and traffic not bound for it is directed away from the VPN.

Comment: It seems as though all traffic is directed over the VPN by default on Windoze, and I can't find a way to change that. Evidenced by directing my browser to any one of those dumpy "whats my IP" sites, with it showing the IP of the VPN server.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea here is very simple. You need to set up your VPN not as the default gateway and below is how you can go about that. Go to your network connections >> VPN connection >> Networking, Advanced and uncheck Use default gateway on remote network. You should be done right there..

Source : http://www.thekonsulthub.com/how-tos/how-to-surf-using-default-windows-connection-even-with-vpn-installed/